# Selecting records with "at least one" condition on 1:n foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables in a SQL Server database: `Submission`, `Quote`, and `Company`. The foreign key relationships are 1:n for `Submission`:`Quote` and `Company`:`Quote`, i.e. a quote belongs to one submission and to one company. I have a query that selects all quotes for those submissions that have *at least one* quote with a specified company:

```
SELECT *
FROM Submission S, Quote Q, Company C
WHERE Q.submissionId = S.submissionId AND
    Q.companyId = C.companyId AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Quote T
        WHERE T.submissionId = S.submissionId AND
            T.companyId = @companyId
    )
ORDER BY S.legalName
```

Is there a more efficient and/or more concise way to accomplish what I'm doing here? I just can't shake the feeling that there should be.

Comment: Changed the query slightly for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM Submission S
INNER JOIN Quote Q   ON Q.submissionId = S.submissionId
INNER JOIN Company C ON Q.companyId = C.companyId 
WHERE  Q.companyId = @companyId
ORDER BY S.legalName
```

### Edit

```
SELECT *
FROM Submission S
INNER JOIN Quote Q   ON Q.submissionId = S.submissionId
INNER JOIN Company C ON Q.companyId = C.companyId 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM Submission Sub
               INNER JOIN Quote Qt  ON Qt.submissionId = Sub.submissionId
               WHERE Sub.submissionId = S.submissionId
                AND  Qt.companyId = @companyId)
ORDER BY S.legalName
```

Comment: I wrote this very thing, but thought there is no way that he's looking for something this simple.  But after going over it and over it (to the point where you posted first (+1)) that is all that OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, this does not accomplish what I'm trying to do. This only selects quotes where `Q.companyId = @companyId`. I need to select ALL quotes for each submission that has a quote for the specified company. So if a submission has four quotes and one is for the specified company, I still need to select the other three quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Join a sub-select statement to get specific submissionid's.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Submission S 
INNER JOIN Quote Q 
        ON Q.submissionId = S.submissionId
INNER JOIN Company C 
        ON Q.companyId =C.companyId  
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT qt.submissionId 
            FROM Quote qt 
            WHERE qt.companyId = @companyId) Q2
        ON Q2.submissionId = S.submissionId
ORDER BY S.legalName
```